# How to create a new tab on Indicator Settings Panel and order inputs there? V5

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I have too many inputs for my indicator I develop so some certain important inputs are harder to find. (E.g. experimental or debugging variables.) This makes the Settings Panel too high so it covers the chart, possibly covering anomalies I'd like to identify and eliminate (thus we need to drag it here and there).

**Is there a way to open new tabs and place certain inputs there?**
[image: Tabs on Indicator Settings Panel]

For example like this syntax:

```
input.bool(false, title="Experimental Thingy Switchy", group="Experiments", tab="Experiments")
input.float(1, title="Experimental Variable I'd need a coffee to know what should be", tab="Experiments")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible. You can `group` them but you have already done that.

Other than that, think about if you really need every input you have.

Can you use one input to do multiple things maybe?

Comment: Good point. Here's a new question which would help me out: :)  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72248819/how-to-address-a-color-transparency-opacity-without-touching-the-color-itself-v