# How to address a color transparency/opacity without touching the color itself? V5

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

For example I have these color variables:

```
Color1 = #334455FF
Color2 = #33445588
```

The only difference is the opacity/transparency component. Can we address this component only, without touching the RGB comps.? For example (improvised obvious syntax concept):

```
Color1 = #334455FF
Color2 = @Color1, opacity=50
```

I think there was some similar function in V4 … (I just wasn't here in that era.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
transp = input.int(0, minval=0,maxval=100)
colbase = input.color(color.yellow)

var color _col = na 

_col := color.new(colbase, transp)

plot(close,'close',_col,3)
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for the `color.t()` function.

> Retrieves the color's transparency.

```
//@version=5
indicator("color.t", overlay=true)
plot(color.t(color.new(color.red, 50)))
```

## Edit:

You can use the `color.r()`, `color.g()`, `color.b()` functions to get the r, g, b components of a color. Then use the `color.rgb()` function to create a new color.

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © vitruvius

//@version=5
indicator("My script")

color1 = color.new(#c9ff73, 0)

color_r = color.r(color1)
color_g = color.g(color1)
color_b = color.b(color1)

color2 = color.rgb(color_r, color_g, color_b, 25)
color3 = color.rgb(color_r, color_g, color_b, 50)
color4 = color.rgb(color_r, color_g, color_b, 75)

plot(0, "1", color1, linewidth=5)
plot(5, "2", color2, linewidth=5)
plot(10, "3", color3, linewidth=5)
plot(15, "4", color4, linewidth=5)
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, no-no. :) I'd like to alter the transparency, not to retrieve it. Color2 = Color1 with transp. 50.

It's interesting though.

Comment: For example I want to use a color but with different transparencies:
Color1 = color.red
Color2 = Color1 with half the transparency
Color3 = Color2 with half the transparency

Or just get the color components of Color1, overrinding it in Color2.

Comment: Please see my edit.